# Promise as a class method call triggers object.then upon resolving

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-proxy

I have an class that contains db methods and it's wrapped in a proxy which handles access to properties. Since the issue is related to promises here is an simplified example code that is reproducing the same issue:

```
const handler = {
  ownKeys(target) {
    return Object.keys(target._attributes)
  },
  get(target, property) {
    console.log(`<-${property}`) // <-- this logs what properties are being accessed
    if (typeof target[property] !== 'undefined') {
        return Reflect.get(target, property)
    }
    return Reflect.get(target._attributes, property)
  },
  set(target, property, value) {
    target._attributes[property] = value
    return true
  }
}
class User {
    static table = 'users'
    static fetch(query = {}, opts = {}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(new this(query))
          }, 500)
        })
    }
    constructor(attributes = {}) {
        this._attributes = attributes
        return new Proxy(this, handler)
    }
}
async function trigger() {
  const user = await User.fetch({test:'test'})
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user._attributes))
}
trigger()
```

Everything works well, during the testing I've added a printout to the proxy to determine performance hit of using such model design, and I noticed that my model get's called from within promise chain.

Example output follows:

```
<-then
<-_attributes
{"test":"test"}
```

I guess that returning `new this(query)` causes the promises to think that maybe it's a promise returned and consequently `.then()` is executed.
Only workaround that I've found is to wrap resolve response inside new array or another object like this:

```
static fetch(query = {}, opts = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([new this(query)])
    }, 500)
  })
}
// Output
// 2
// <-_attributes
// {"test":"test"}
```

What I'm wondering is, is this correct way and are there other solutions to this side effect?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the behavior you see now? The value passed to `resolve` maybe be a "thenable" so it checks if `.then` exists. That is expected.

Comment: There is nothing wrong, I was just wondering if this is expected behavior and is there a way around it. Thing is that I wanted to prevent unnecessary calls to proxy as its performance is questionable in some cases.

Comment: Resolving with "*`new this(query)` causes the promises to think that maybe it's a promise returned*" - yes, exactly. "*…and consequently `.then()` is executed*" - no, it's not executed because it doesn't exist. But it is accessed, to *try* to execute it in case it is a method.

Comment: Why exactly is this an issue, what is the problem that you need a solution for?

Comment: Well.. accessed you are right, I was logging access to properties, my bad. It's not a problem per se but as I wrote on other comment it might become a problem when large data-sets are handled with lots of promises due to slow performance of proxies. Escaping the proxy with encapsulating the resolve value is a usable hack, I just wanted to make sure that is the right way to do it, thanks for the comments..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All objects passed to as a result of a promise is always checked to see if it has a `then` property. If it does, that function is used to queue up entries to get a final value. This is why logic like

```
Promise.resolve()
   .then(() => {
       return Promise.resolve(45);
   })
   .then(result => {
       console.log(result);
   });
```

logs `45` instead of a promise object. Since the promise objects has a `.then` property, it is used to unwrap the promises value. The same behavior happens in your `resolve(new this(query))` case, because it needs to know if there is a value to unwrap.

As you've said, commented in your post, you could certainly wrap the instance with a non-proxy, e.g.

```
resolve({ value: new this(query) })
```

which would check for `.then` on *that* object instead of on your proxy, but then you have to do `.value` to actually get the proxy, which can be a pain.

At the end of the day, that is a choice you'll have to make.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it sheds some light to the issue in hand. I suspected something like this, but is always good to have a confirmation. Anyway I'll just use a destructor on the awaited promise and that will do the trick without having ugly .value. Something like this : const [user] = await User.fetch({ username })